# How to display Featured Image in post type of ACF FORM as Image field

Tags: php, frontend, advanced-custom-fields, cpu-word

Here's my code at functions.php and still can't set as featured image in the post type of the blog.

```
 add_action('acf/save_post', 'acf_set_featured_image');

function acf_set_featured_image($post_id){
    $value = get_field('daily_selfie', $post_id);

    if($value != ''){
        add_post_meta($post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $value);
    }

    return $value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function acf_set_featured_image( $value, $post_id, $field  ){

    if($value != ''){
        //Add the value which is the image ID to the _thumbnail_id meta data for the current post
        add_post_meta($post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $value);
    }
    return $value;
}

// acf/update_value/name={$field_name} - filter for a specific field based on it's name
add_filter('acf/update_value/name=foo', 'acf_set_featured_image', 10, 3);
```